# How to create database with Liquibase

Tags: java, mysql, maven, liquibase

- I am trying to use `Liquibase` to create database that does **not** exists.
- I have downloaded `MySQL` and not made any change in it
- My maven plugin code looks like

  ```
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
          <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
          <configuration>
              <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
              <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
              <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myApp?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</url>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>process-resources</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>update</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
  ```

When I run `mvn clean install`, I see error as

```
Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.1.1:update (default) on project database_seed: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'myApp' -> [Help 1]
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: You may want to consider creating schema using <sql> in changeset. If nothing else helps.

Comment: If someone is searching help on how to create fresh MySQL schema through liquibase then this question ends our search. Following createDatabaseIfNotExist=true serves the purpose.

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you're not passing a username or password as part of your config:

([from the liquibase maven documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/))

```
<configuration>
  <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
  <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
  <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myApp?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</url>
  <username>liquibaseTest</username>
  <password>pass</password>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you are using application.properties for configuration in spring-boot, please use the key-value pairs below:

`spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:11030/myAppcreateDatabaseIfNotExist=true`

`spring.datasource.username=liquibaseTest`
`spring.datasource.password=pass`