# Postgres database creation with liquibase

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

I'm trying to create an empty database using [liqubase](https://www.liquibase.org/). I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745527/how-to-create-database-with-liquibase) approach to do this, but the problem is it doesn't work for me.

I use Postgresql 10 and there are my configurations for maven and liqubase:

```
 <plugin>
          <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
          <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.5</version>
          <configuration>
             <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
  </plugin>
```

And my `liqubase.properties`:

```
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase/db.changelog.xml
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
dropFirst=false
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/auth?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
username=postgres
password=root
```

The error on `mvn clean package` is:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "auth" does not
>   exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Liquibase will not create a database that does not exist at all. I also imagine that the url parameter `?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` that is referenced in the linked question/answer is probably MySql specific.

Answer (score 3):

This is slightly beyond the scope of your question, but you could use liquibase against a [Docker postgres instance](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/), and per the docker-library's documentation on [ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/#:~:text=ENVIRONMENT%20VARIABLES),  set `POSTGRES_DB` to "auth" (in your case), and it will create the "auth" db when the docker image launches, with which liquibase can then interact.